How to split an A0 document into A4 pages to be printed true to size?
I have an A0 design in Inkscape of a sewing pattern. What is the easiest way to make this into printable A4 PDFs, in such a way that it prints true to size taking into account printer margins of the A4 sheets? It would also need some way to mark how to puzzele the individual sheets together.
The goal is to have a downloadable sewing pattern that can be printed and assembled at home. I want my source document to stay the A0 design, so I'm looking for a largely automatic way of doing this - I don't want to have to go through a lengthy process every time something changes in the original design.

is this pattern one large piece that spans the whole A0 or is it a group of parts that could be split into A4 groups?

Yes indeed one large A0. Some people want to send the A0 off to print at a copy shop, others want to print to A4 at home, and I want to single source the design.

You can use Adobe Reader/Acrobat for tiled printing. Here are the instructions

From Inkscape print a PDF file then use pdfposter to split it into A4 pages using the following command:
pdfposter -m a4 -p a0 inputfile.pdf splitfile.pdf

This looks very useful, and I can script this into my workflow. Thanks.

if using in house extensions dint work well, try PosteRazor to split large images into A4 pages for printing.
Ensure A0 design is properly laid out in Inkscape.
Export A0 design as an image file (e.g., PNG or JPEG).
Import image into PosteRazor and configure split into A4 pages with overlap.
Manually add assembly marks to each A4 page using image editing software.
Test print A4 pages for alignment and accuracy.
Export assembled A4 pages as a PDF file.
PosteRazor simplifies the process, ensuring true-to-size printing and easy assembly.
PS:i dont promote any tool . i suggested something that worked before.

this is not a very good idea, you're converting the vector file into lower resolution raster images. That might not result in a good quality printing.
